# Annoying problem on Careers 2.0

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs

I was on Careers 2.0 today trying to update my current employer information. If you leave off the job title, the site appears to accept it (no errors or any such thing). However, nothing is saved. This is then unknown to the user until you reload the page.

Can you please fix this?

Comment: Wait I forgot to phrase this in the form of a question.. edit incoming

Comment: A rare miss for Mr. Craver...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Agree that it’s annoying. We’ve added validation so that the Job Title is required, preventing this situation.